# MVC 4 Application : Login failed sql exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the error

> SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'raam030'

for my ASP.NET MVC4 application. Works fine on my development machine using local SQL Server but when I deployed it to the web hosting this is what I am getting. I have searched for same questions, there are many but none of them helped me so far.

I have the stack trace below, I triple-checked and made sure my connection string is correct and SQL Server authentication is correct. Though my hosting services connection string does not require password information I tried variations without and with hard coded password and user name.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="RMSDelta" 
        connectionString="Data Source=mssql2.openhost.net.nz;Integrated Security=False;User ID=myusername; Password=mypassword;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Network Library=dbmssocn;Packet Size=4096" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am using code first approach. My database name is the same I used as connection string name, same name used to pass as connection string in my context class. Made sure the provider name is correct. Except the data access part (and page which needed data) every other page works fine with my application.. I am not really sure what else to make out of this stack trace??

Please help me.

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'raam030'.]
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +1316
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +85
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +349
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +265
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +34
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +163
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +40
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.]
>
> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +163
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +39
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +46
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +117
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +453
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +56
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +40
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +63
>
>   ASP._Page_Views_Default_Qualifications_cshtml.Execute() in d:\vhosts\rameshsivaraman.me\httpdocs\Views\Default\Qualifications.cshtml:45
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +209
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +234
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +264
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19() +20
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +71
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +128
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +30
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9041917
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Comment: I guess it's not an issue with your application and it's due to your Sql server configuration, try to connect to your instance providing your account in SSMS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. My local version works perfect, issue is with deployed one. They have given me only a limited version admin panel for SQL. But I made sure the credentials are correct and in fact I had another data base on it which was working perfectly and with same connection string parameters...

Answer (score 0):

How silly things are sometimes... It seems my hosting company somehow requires a password with more than 6 characters to authenticate into sql server, I was using 4 character password earlier when I used a longer one it did work, however the hosting providers Plesk panel accepts the password with 4 characters when I set up the account!!!. I had to spend half my day fiddling with this thing, I am gonna shoot an email right now asking why they don't display any caution about this... Thanks friends..